# Merging rows SQL - Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this table on MS Access:

```
Name | Week   | Manager | Sales
John | 201409 | Marcelo | 53
John | 201410 | Marcelo | 20
John | 201410 | Raquel  | 30
John | 201411 | Raquel  | 53
```

I have to merge Week 201410 by the max Sales and choose which Manager. After this I'd like to sum the Total Sales for this two and make like this:

```
Name | Week   | Manager | Sales
John | 201409 | Marcelo | 53
John | 201410 | Raquel  | 50
John | 201411 | Raquel  | 53
```

Could anybody help me? I tried a lot of SQL and couldn't do nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each row had a unique identifier (Primary Key), it would be a lot simpler. However, you work with the data you have, not with the data you wish you had, so here's my circuitous way of accomplishing it. You could combine this all into one query and avoid using temporary tables; I split it out this way to make it convenient to understand, rather than being concise.

First, extract the highest Sales for each Name-Week combination:

```
SELECT Name, Week, MAX(Sales)
INTO #MaxSales
FROM [YourTable]
GROUP BY Name, Week
```

Use this information to get the Manager that you should use for each week (We use TOP 1 to resolve the case where two managers have the same sales for the same Name/Week; I'm not sure how you would want to resolve this.):

```
SELECT Name, Week, Manager
INTO #MaxSalesManager
FROM [YourTable]
INNER JOIN #MaxSales
ON [YourTable].Name = #MaxSales.Name
AND [YourTable].Week = #MaxSales.Week
WHERE [YourTable].Sales = #MaxSales.Sales
```

Now you can extract the information you need:

```
SELECT [YourTable].Name, [YourTable].Week, #MaxSalesManager.Manager, SUM([YourTable].Sales)
FROM [YourTable]
INNER JOIN #MaxSalesManager
ON [YourTable].Name = #MaxSalesManager.Name
AND [YourTable].Week = #MaxSalesManager.Week
GROUP BY [YourTable].Name, [YourTable].Week, #MaxSalesManager.Manager
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

Combining them all into one query:

```
SELECT [YourTable].Name, 
       [YourTable].Week, 
       #MaxSalesManager.Manager, 
       SUM([YourTable].Sales)
FROM [YourTable]
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Name, Week, Manager
    FROM [YourTable]
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT Name, Week, MAX(Sales)
        FROM [YourTable]
        GROUP BY Name, Week) AS #MaxSales
    ON [YourTable].Name = #MaxSales.Name
    AND [YourTable].Week = #MaxSales.Week
    WHERE [YourTable].Sales = #MaxSales.Sales) AS #MaxSalesManager
ON [YourTable].Name = #MaxSalesManager.Name
AND [YourTable].Week = #MaxSalesManager.Week
GROUP BY [YourTable].Name, [YourTable].Week, #MaxSalesManager.Manager
```

Comment: That helped me a lot taserian! Thank you! But I don't know how to combine all these in one query.. How can I do that? And when I use the TOP 1 it returns me just one value (changed to a usual SELECT and returns me what I wanted with the problem you told me for the same name/week in two managers). Any ideia? Appreciate a lot your help mate!!!

Comment: And another question.. What if I add other columns? For example I have different department, saleschannel and function.. How can I add it without messing up with the query? ps: I'm new at using SQL as you could see :)

Comment: I've made a condensed query in my answer. Also, I removed the TOP 1, but you'll have an issue if two or more managers accomplish the same max sales for a Name-Week. That would be better accomplished as a function, but as a newcomer to SQL, I don't want to go that far.

Lastly, adding more columns to the end result is simple: just add them right after the SELECT at the very top and the GROUP BY at the bottom. Make sure you don't include the SUM() in the GROUP BY.

Comment: Thanks for your time taserian, but unfortunately it is not working. It is giving me a message "Enter Parameter Value: MaxSales.Sales".. I'm trying to move the things from a place to another but it is not working at all.. Any clue?

Comment: Done taserian, I did it! hehe thank you! One more thing if you could help me.. I'm adding other columns that are duplicating again the week and I want it to be sum the sales as the manager. I mean, I could have two departments in a week, for example, or two sales channel.. For the same week manager problem, I have another amount hat could be checked, like "calls".. How can I use it to eliminate the problem? Thank you very much again!!!

Comment: The rest of it is up to you. Without more information as to how you want to group, add and summarize results, along with example data, it's too difficult to speculate. The above was intended to help you see how to resolve the general issue so you can hammer out the specifics, rather than completely fix your specific problem. It would be worthwhile for you to learn some SQL before tackling this type of report again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT [Name], [Week], [Manager], SUM([Sales]) as Sales1
From [YourTable]
GROUP BY [Name], [Week], [Manager]
```

I did not test this so let me know what errors you get.

Comment: just change the column names to be more specific and fix the tables to be more understandable.

Comment: I changed the names, but don't forget to change the [YourTable] value in the query. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: the same.. the thing is I want to sum the sales from two managers on a week which has been duplicate and choose the manager one who has the higher value, and in that way doesn't even sum the Sales, any clue?